# On Button Click, a DIV Fades Out, While Another DIV Fades in at the Same Location

Tags: jquery, onclick, fade

I have a fully functioning image slider floated next to an unordered list of (3) DIVS.  The first color of the slider corresponds with the first DIV.  I'm trying to create an effect whereby when someone clicks the 'next' button on the slider, not only will the slider transition to the next color, but the DIV floated next to it will fade out, while the next DIV, which corresponds to the next color fades in.

I have the slider working, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to allow each click of the button to also continuously loop through each DIV that corresponds to the colors of the slider.

I'm a relative beginner to jquery, but I can understand some of its more complex logic, I just can't figure out.  I tried making the overflow of the DIV's hidden, and follow the same process of image slider, but with no luck.

I'd really appreciate any help.  A Jsfiddle of what I have so far is below.

```
    <ul id="slide_info">
    <div id="info1">
        <h2>Blue Header</h2>
        <p>Description</p>
    </div>  

    <div id="info2">
        <h2>Red Header</h2>
        <p>Description</p>
    </div>  

    <div id="info3">
        <h2>Yellow Header</h2>
        <p>Description</p>
    </div>  


</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lgwj/Lb6p87ft/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is. You can tweak the height and widths of divs according to your requirement.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  
 var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
 var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
 var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
 var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
 
 $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
 $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });
    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

  var slideinfoWidth = $('.desc').width();
  var slideinfoHeight = $('.desc').height();
  var sliderUlinfoWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
    
      $('#slide_info').css({ width: slideinfoWidth, height: slideinfoHeight });
  $('#info').css({ width: sliderUlinfoWidth});

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 300, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
        $('#info').animate({
            left: - slideinfoWidth
        }, 300, function () {
            $('.desc:first-child').appendTo('#info');
            $('#info').css('left', '');
        });
    };
 
    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  float:right;
  width: 50% !important;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 550px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 639.5px;
  height: 550px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-image:url(prev-icon.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}


a.control_next {
  right: 0;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;}
  
  
  
 #feat {
   width: 100%;}
  
  
.feat_slides {
 background-position: center top;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;}
 
#feat_slide1 {
 background: #006699;}
 
#feat_slide2 {
 background: #CC0033;}
 
#feat_slide3 {
 background:#FFFF99;}
 
 
#slide_info {
 float: left;
 width:50%;
 padding-left: 0;}
 
.slide_info {
 }
 
#info1, #info2, #info3 {
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 50%;
 height: 500px;
 padding-top: 215px;
 padding-left: 30px;}

.desc{
  float:left;
}
#slide_info{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="feat">
 <ul id="slide_info"><div id="info">
     <div class="desc" id="info1">
   <h2>Blue Header</h2>
   <p>Description</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="desc" id="info2">
   <h2>Red Header</h2>
   <p>Description</p>
        </div> 
        
        <div class="desc" id="info3">
   <h2>Yellow Header</h2>
   <p>Description</p>
        </div> 
        </div>
 </ul>
   
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next" id="toggle_info">BUTTON</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="feat_slides" id="feat_slide1"></li>
    
    <li class="feat_slides" id="feat_slide2"></li>
    
    <li class="feat_slides" id="feat_slide3"></li>
  </ul>  
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This works well and is pretty close to what I'm trying to accomplish, now I have a better understanding of how the logic.  Thanks a lot for your energy.

Answer (score 0):

The first obvious thing I saw was a `div` as an immediate child of a `ul`.
Even if that may not cause any issue, that definitely is invalid HTML. Most modern browsers *are fixing* this... But still it is a bad thing to do.

So the `div` elements inside `<ul id="slide_info">` have to be wrapped by `<li>` and `</li>`.

Then, about your code, you used an ingenious `appendTo` trick to "cycle" through the list items... Why not just use the same trick?

Now about fading in/out... There are animation delay to take in account. You can use callbacks, which are functions executed on completion of another.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Variable declarations
  var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  // Positionning
  $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
  $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

  // ??? Why this "re-ordering" on load?
  $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

  // Hide all slide-info item except the first
  $("#slide_info li").not("#slide_info li:nth-child(1)").hide();

  // Click handler
  $('a.control_next').click(function () {

    // Animate the slides
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: - slideWidth
    }, 300, function () {
      $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });

    // Animate slide infos
    // Get the visible one into a variable
    var visible = $("#slide_info li:visible");
    // Fade it out and fade in the next one
    visible.fadeOut(300, function(){
      // This is a callback, so after the fadeOut:
      visible.next().fadeIn(300,function(){
        // This is also a callback...
        // "visible" is now faded out, but still in this variable.
        // Append it to the end of the list.
        visible.appendTo("#slide_info");
      });
    })
  });

});
```

[**Your Fiddle updated**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/esfb1w4j/)

Comment: Brilliant.  I'm a beginner at web development and I still have a tendency to make beginner mistakes, but this solution was exactly what I was looking for.  I'm thankful for tools like stackoverflow to help in my learning process.  Thanks for your time and thought.